# How to run an ArangoDB container in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, arangodb

I'm trying to create an ArangoDB cluster in ECS using the default `arangodb/arangodb-starter` container but when I start my ECS Task, I'm getting an error saying that `/usr/sbin/arangod` was not found.

I pulled the `arangodb/arangodb-starter` image locally using `docker pull` and then I tagged it according to the push commands from ECR, I pushed it to ECR and I created an ECS Task (Fargate) for it. I created a service in ECS to start that task and the container starts, but the ECS Service logs show this error:

```
|INFO| Starting arangodb version 0.15.5, build 7832707 component=arangodb

[ERROR| Cannot find arangod (expected at /usr/sbin/arangod). component=arangodb

How to solve this:

1 - Install ArangoDB locally or run the ArangoDB starter in docker. (see README for details).
```

I started the exact same container by tag locally and it works. Why doesn't it work in ECS?

**edit** The ECS Task definition is in the snippet below:

```js
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:123456789:task-definition/dev-arangodb-server:1",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "dev-arangodb-server",
            "image": "123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/arangodb:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "links": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8529,
                    "hostPort": 8529,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [],
            "command": [],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "password"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "storage",
                    "containerPath": "/mnt/storage",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [],
            "dnsServers": [],
            "dnsSearchDomains": [],
            "extraHosts": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
            "dockerLabels": {},
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/dev-arangodb-server",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "dev-arangodb-server",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/dev-aws-ecs-ecr-power-user",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 1,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "storage",
            "host": {}
        }
    ],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "3072",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2022-11-03T08:43:25.264Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/MY_USER",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:createdFrom",
            "value": "ecs-console-v2"
        },
        {
            "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:stackId",
            "value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:123456789:stack/ECS-Console-V2-TaskDefinition-e1519bf7-ff78-423a-951d-2bc8d79242ec/925d88d0-5b53-11ed-97a3-066ee48e3b9b"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your task definition also?

Comment: Updated. Sorry I forgot to paste it before.

Comment: I just ran that image in my EKS fargate cluster and it showed the same error like you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This page is about programming questions. For questions about general software, please ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). For (professional) system and network administration, see [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). Make sure to check the help pages and especially what is on-topic on each site before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested on my cluster and seems like that image is not running with default options like yours task definition. That image is not documented so we don't know how to start it correctly

Please try this [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/arangodb) and do the same process. Remember the environment, or you will face this issue.

> error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
> You need to specify one of ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD, ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE, ARANGO_NO_AUTH and ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

Comment: I also had to manually configure `ulimit` in the Task Definition JSON and set it to `[ { "name": "nofile", "softLimit": 16384, "hardLimit": 32768 } ]`. This did the trick and the container is up and running and I can access the web interface!

Comment: Oh, so it has the resources requirements. Next time you need to read the documentations first before running into somethings else